# fullcalendar ie error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fullcalendar

I am getting a js error message on ie8 and it is stopping my site from loading.

It the error msg is Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 23:58:36 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 180
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://realcashback.com.au/v2/system/javascript/main.js
```

on line 180 char 9  is `,` here is the section of code. from 172 in my code to 182

```
if (title) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    {
        title: title,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        allDay: allDay,

    },
    true // make the event "stick"
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a stray dangling comma after the "allDay" property in that object literal.

IE doesn't like that in its older versions, but IE8 should be OK with it (however you shouldn't be in the habit of doing it).  Is it possible that you've got IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode?

The reason to avoid those is that while IE8 is OK with commas at the end of property lists in object literals and array constants, it behaves differently than other browsers in the case of arrays.  A trailing comma is interpreted as meaning that you want an additional element in the array with no value (`undefined`). Because that's weird and useless, it's better to just avoid trailing commas in general.

*edit* — oh well I notice that your UserAgent string claims it's in compatibility mode.

Comment: I removed that allDay comma and it worked, I totally missed that THANKS! yeah i put it in compatibility mode to see if it was an ie8 error. but instead its my error :)